# Can I share a external texture between 2 OpenGL contexts, Android

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, opengl-es

I'm creating 2 threads. Each thread has its own EGL contexts.
One thread is in native, where I will render to a texture, another thread is in Java, in which I want to sample from that texture and render to the screen / to an encoder (doesn't matter).
I can't make it work.
I've tried generating the texture on either of the threads. What I noticed is the texture Ids are duplicated on both threads (I have other textures that are not meant to be shared).

My question is, is it possible to share a texture between 2 threads (and contexts)?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Thanks to Andon and some Googling, I was able to make it work. I created one context in Java on thread one, and the called `eglGetCurrentContext()` to get the EGLContext in C++. Later, I created the second context in C++ on the second thread with:

`eglCreateContext(mEglDisplay, mEglConfig, sharedContext, contextAttribs);`

Where sharedContext is the first context.

Comment: Fence sync objects would be the preferred method of synchronization, but I don't think you have those in OpenGL ES? _(incidentally, your question is tagged wrong - it should be OpenGL ES)_

Comment: You say "external texture" in the title, but then in the question that's not mentioned, and it sounds like you're just using a regular OpenGL texture. Can you clarify which one it is?

Comment: Yes I am using an  EXTERNAL texture.

Comment: With external textures, you should be able to share the image data between contexts that are not in the same share group. They even work between processes. Of course you will need a texture object in each share group, but the textures can be backed by the same image. Still, as long as everything is in the same process, there's no big point to bother with external textures. Putting the contexts in the same share group and using a regular texture is probably much simpler.

Comment: @Reto can you please back what you said with an example. I was trying to share a an external texture between 2 processes and from what I read it was impossible, and I never got it to work. Also you said having texture be shared in a shared context group is much simpler. Simpler than what? What is the other alternative? Can you please  give us more details  and an example?

Comment: The "show + capture camera" activity in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) does this, sharing an external texture received from the Camera with two EGL contexts in different threads (one draws on the screen, one feeds a MediaCodec encoder). It gets a little sticky because the display context is managed by GLSurfaceView, which isn't all that into sharing.

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer instead of in the question?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, resource sharing between contexts is possible.

The command streams in shared contexts are not synchronized though; if you upload data in one thread and use it in another you have to be extra careful that the upload is actually finished first (`glFinish (...)` followed by some synchronization construct of your own, like a semaphore, will do).

Now, the million dollar question—do you have any control over the creation of these contexts? That is necessary to do resource sharing in EGL. You only need to create one yourself; if you have the other given to you already, you can use it as your share context when creating the second.

Comment: I have full control over both contexts. I am creating them both. What does glFinish do? And as I mentioned, it did not work. The rendering on the texture on one thread works. But when I sample from that texture Id from another thread, in the other context. I get a blank screen.

Comment: @MichaelP: `glFinish (...)` blocks until all commands leading up to it are finished. Otherwise, GL has a tendency to put commands into a queue and execute them whenever the GPU gets around to it. That's usually good, but it's bad, bad, bad when you're doing multi-threaded rendering. You need to call `glFinish (...)` immediately after the thing that's producing the texture in one thread and once that command returns you can signal to the render thread that there's valid texture data waiting to be drawn. Otherwise the two threads operate asynchronously and it's a mess.

Comment: @MichaelP: Ordinarily in a single thread / single context render scenario you never have to think about this stuff, GL automatically does this sort of synchronization. But when you're using two separate contexts, they each execute commands in parallel and you need to make sure the order the commands execute in is consistent. _However, none of this will work at all if you don't establish one of the contexts as a share context by passing it to `eglCreateContext (...)`._

Comment: It worked! Thank you @Andon I will update the question with the solution